Handling Exceptions in Coroutine Kotlin
I'm encountering an issue with handling exceptions thrown within a coroutine in my Android ViewModel. I have a function addCategory in my CategoryViewModel that adds a category to a repository. I want to handle exceptions thrown during this process and display error messages in my UI.
However, when an exception is thrown within the coroutine (for example, if the category limit is exceeded), the error message is logged but not displayed in the UI (this behaviour does not happen when the "Maximum character limit reached" Exception triggers). I want to ensure that the error message is properly propagated to the fragment and displayed in the TextInputLayout.
CategoryViewModel:
class CategoryViewModel(private val categoryRepository: CategoriesRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
        throwable.message?.let {
            Log.d("Error", it)
        }
    }

   fun addCategory(categoryName: String, categoryIconId: Int?, type: String) {
        if (categoryName.length > 20) throw Exception("Maximum character limit reached")

        viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
            val categoryCount = categoryRepository.getCategoryCount(null).first()
            if (categoryCount >= 10) throw Exception("Maximum category limit reached")

            val categoryObject = Category(name = categoryName, iconId = categoryIconId, type = type)
            categoryRepository.insertCategory(categoryObject)
        }
    }
}

Fragment:
try {
    categoryVM.addCategory(categoryName, iconId, type)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    textInputLayout.error = e.message
}

I tried throwing the Exception from the exceptionHandler but that just crashes the app.
    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
        throwable.message?.let {
            throw Exception(it)
        }
    }


Exceptions thrown by a coroutine are not propagated to the function that called launch. That function has likely already returned successfully before the coroutine has done much of anything yet. I recommend that within your coroutine use try/catch and within the catch block, update some MutableStateFlow or LiveData that holds error messages. Your UI can subscribe to that to show errors to the user.

As according to your question, I would like to answer more related to catching the exception in the Coroutines. I feel if you implement the exception catching logic correctly, you can figure out what to do further.
You can try-catch the exceptions using the coroutineScope and supervisorScope
In the coroutineScope when there raises an exception, the rest of the operations are not performed and cancelled immediately. Whereas, in the supervisorScope you shall place the try-catch at the individual block or operation, it catches the exceptions and does not immediate terminate/cancels the operations like in the coroutineScope
You can see there implementation and further read the blogs, documentation etc related to it. I just share some specific supervisorScope & coroutineScope, but you can find more content related to it.
